# 2.8.1 Login loop

Tags: login, 2.8

I having a login problem with EE 2.8.1. When you type in the username and password on the front end login screen you get redirected back to the same screen and do not seem to get logged in. No errors. The username and password are correct.

I believe this issue may be related to cookies and sessions but I have cleared all cookies, tried in all browsers in incognito windows and it still won't work. I have a 2.7.1 install on the same server and this doesn't have the problem

When I go to site `domain.dev/admin.php` it redirects me to `domain.dev/admin.php?/cp/login?return=` and when I type the username and password it redirects with what I think is a session ID.

To add some additional information, if I disable cookies for the domain I get directed to a page and gives me an error:

"This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out that Structure 3.3.1 is the culprit when you set it to redirect to Structure on login. You can get past it by editing the config file and change `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'y';` to `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';`

Answer (score 3):

If you get in touch with Travis at Structure, there's a BETA which will resolve the 'redirect to structure on login' with 2.8x.

Answer (score 0):

Yes — It's a bug that seems to pop up on EE point releases.

But you don't have to disable Structure completely while waiting for a fix: Just turn off (i.e. set **enabled** to **n** in the exp_extensions table) Structure_ext's hook into **sessions_start**.