# Can't login to control panel (redirects back to login)

Tags: login, focus-lab-master-config

I'm having the same [issue described here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/398/login-page-returns-to-the-login-page-doesnt-log-me-in). I've tried the working solution but it hasn't worked for. In config.local.php I have `$env_config['cookie_domain']   = 'buckley.dev';` and I am still unable to login. This site is using the focuslab multi environment config set up in case that is relevant.

This was working last night when I installed EE 2.8.1 but when I tried to login this morning it won't let me. I am also unable to log in to the staging site.

I have also tried logging in with Firefox unsuccessfully.

In config.master.php I have the following

```
//$env_config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$env_config['cookie_path'] = "";
$env_config['cookie_prefix'] = "bulkley";
$env_config['admin_session_type'] = "c";
$env_config['user_session_type'] = "c";
$env_config['require_ip_for_login'] = "n";
$env_config['require_ip_for_posting'] = "n"; 
$env_config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```

Also I am able to login via a front end form so I know my user/password are correct. I am however unable to access the CP.

Interestingly if I login via the CP (and get redirected) and then I view the front end of the site when previously logged out, I am now logged in. So the issue isn't that I'm not logging in but that **I can't access the control panel when logged in**.

Comment: have you tried: $env_config['user_session_type'] = 's';
$env_config['admin_session_type'] = 's'; ?

Comment: Erwin, yes. Have found the solution see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Some more googling and I found the answer [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/2-8-1-login-loop). The issue is with Structure and setting it to redirect to structure on login.

> I finally found out that Structure 3.3.1 is the culprit when you set
>   it to redirect to Structure on login. You can get past it by editing
>   the config file and change $config['allow_extensions'] = 'y'; to
>   $config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';

Have done this and turned off the redirect within structure and all is good now.

Comment: I gather currently no other issues with Structure 3.3.1 and EE2.8.1? Starting a new build next week.

Comment: Erwin, that is correctly